# how to design android layout support for different devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

i am starting a developing an android app.so now i'm developing a UI layouts for it.i want clarifying some problems of that UI designs. these are my problems.

1.How to design layouts support for all devices(small,normal,large,xlarge)..now i crate one activity for these different types of layouts.these way is that correct or wrong..may i think this is wasting time and app size will be high..

2.if have any method for support one layout file for each one activity? please suggest it.

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly go through official document. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0):

Use dimen.xml for different screen sizes.
Create dimen.xml and add screen width/ size. 
Eg: for tablets give screen width 600 dp  =

> dimen.xml(sw-600)

.
and add dimensions in dimen.xml with same name and different values.
Eg. in dimen.xml

```
`<dimen name="_1sdp">1sp</dimen>`
```

in dimen.xml(sw-600dp)

```
<dimen name="_1sdp">2sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `constraintLayout` to create responsive UI. [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) for documentation.
You can use `match_parent` and use some `margin` or `padding` to make your view looking good.

Answer (score 0):

This link here should get you started: [android layout support](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) . At the very minimum, you should have a UI design that has some room for flexibility, and scales properly when viewed in different orientations or screen sizes.  More complicated changes are supported by having alternate layout resource files.  Here are a few more links that explain how to do these things:

[Using constraint layout to create flexible layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and [Providing alternate resource files](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)